# JSONObject from StatusJSONImpl using twitter4j

Tags: java, json, twitter, twitter4j

In my implementation of StatusListener I am trying to get the Status object in a form of JSONObject.
in the OnStatust(Status status) method when i did System.out.println(status.toString()); I realized that the status is StatusJSONImpl... Is there a way I can transfer that object to JSONobject without having to manually parse it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just re-wrote some classes and one interface to allow the extraction of raw data in the shape of JSON Object format.